# Why angular material tabs recreate component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a material design in my angular application.

```
        <mat-tab-group [dynamicHeight]="true">
            <mat-tab label="tab1">
                <ng-template matTabContent>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="map-container-outer">
                            <div class="map-container">
                               <my-comp1></my-comp1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="tab2">
                <ng-template matTabContent>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                           <my-comp2></my-comp2>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
```

When I selct tab2 and tab1 again, the components (`my-comp1, my-comp2`) recreating.

Comment: What makes you think components are recreated?

Comment: When I change tab, the controller(my-com2) constructor fires all time. So my input data losing after change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `<ng-template matTabContent>` you load tabs content in lazy way. Remove them in order to use eager load of all tabs:

```
<mat-tab-group [dynamicHeight]="true">
    <mat-tab label="tab1">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="map-container-outer">
                <div class="map-container">
                    <my-comp1></my-comp1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab2">
      <div class="tab-content">
              <my-comp2></my-comp2>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the lazy-loading features of Angular Material tabs.

Documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading

Remove the `matTabContent` will fallback to eager loading and avoid the issue.

Comment: whan I remove matTabContent , the content becomes empty.

Comment: I meant to remove the attribute, not the whole content